# Static typing in pyDatalog: Possible?

Tags: python, static-typing, mypy, pydatalog

For instance, using the [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) library, one can specify that a function inputs a string and outputs a string, like this:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello, {}'.format(name)
```

In pyDatalog, one can define (say) a unary function a single value at a time, like this:

```
+(favoriteWords[0] == "cats")
```

Is there some way to specify that the argument to favoriteWords must be a single integer, and the output must be a string?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported by pyDatalog.

Comment: I suspect you're the guy who maintains pydatalog, given that you answered 11 of the 20 questions about it -- but is there a way I could be more sure?

Comment: This is correct, although I have not contributed to pyDatalog for a while now.